# "svn checkout" not working on Mac Silicon

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, apple-silicon

I installed SVN on my MacBook Silicon with the M1 chip using HomeBrew. When I run:

```
which svn
```

It shows

```
/usr/local/bin/svn
```

I can also run

```
svn log
```

which return a statement that says the current directory is not a working copy.

But when I run

```
svn co the_svn_url
```

It returns:

```
Unknown subcommand: 'checkout the_svn_url'
```

The version of svn that I installed is 1.14.0.

This only happens on Mac silicon. On other Macs, svn works. And if I copy the svn repository to my Mac silicon, svn commit and svn update works fine.

I've also added this in my .zshrc file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/svn
```

I need svn to deploy a 15-year old legacy project. Other people working on that project are unable to migrate to git. Right now, I have to use another Mac to deploy.

Is there any way to make svn work on Mac Silicon? Has SVN stopped upgrading and I'll have to copy the repositories manually from now on?

Comment: can you share the svn version that is being used. `svn --version`

Comment: @SiddharthKaul It's 1.14.0. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @OliverZhang Any updates on how you resolved this issue or you had to abandon it?